# Do you know about status date changes in Elsevier editorial

Tags: publications

I submitted an article to an Elsevier Journal in (Jan, 2018)
The status and the status date changed after one week in "under review".
Now status remains "Under review" but the status date is new (Sep 2018)
Could you please tell me what it means?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means something went wrong with the review process. For example either of these could have happened:

- The editor handling your paper resigned from the editorial board, and the journal assigned a new editor.
- The reviewer who was reviewing your paper submitted a review, which updates the status to "required reviews complete" or to "decision in progress", but the editor decided the review was poor and invited new reviewers.

One thing that didn't happen is "nothing". Something definitely happened, or the status would not update.